# Enabling apache options based on a request header

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to use different apache options
if a HTTP header is present.

For example, something like:

```
<IfHeader "MyHeader">
  SSLOptions +ExportCertData
  SSLVerifyClient optional
</IfHeader>
```

The "IfHeader" directive does not exist.
Is it possible with SetEnvIf or some other directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behavior, by asking for a different file,
when the header is present:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:MyHeader} .+
RewriteRule .* index_symlink.php [QSA,L]

<Files "index_symlink.php">
    SSLOptions +ExportCertData
    SSLVerifyClient optional
</Files>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried re-writing the URL internally to a location that you can configure the way you want?

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:MyHeader} .+
RewriteRule (.*) $1/special [R,L]

<Location ~ "/special$">
(...)
</Location>
```

Comment: It is a nice idea. Is the redirect needed? The configuration may even be done in .htaccess, if using <Files> instead of <Location>.

Comment: Hi, Ivo. You said the condition is based on a header value - I'm not familiar with another way of evaluating headers inside the Apache config.  Note that the redirect is internal to Apache (ie.: the client will not receive a 3xx response with a Location: header). I'd give that one a try - if it works please answer your own question. :-)

Comment: I tried the [R] flag. It does an external redirect. That is consistent with the mod_rewrite documentation. But you deserve the bounty, your answer lead to the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

proxying.

if you receive headers formatted in a certain way, direct them to a server on another port configured as you wish, or another server on your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

may be setup several http server instances (with diffirent configs) as back end
and use proxy_mod/redirect on front end ?